# Copy and archive directories and only files older than x Days

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I've search and i've tried. I know i'm not very good at powershell but i am starting to thing this isn't possible.

What I am trying to do is move all the contents of my C:\Data that are X days old and archive them.

Sounds easy.. BUT if
C:\data\Subject contains files from 2015 until Current. I only want to archive files that are X days old. so the new archived path would be C:\DataBackup and in there it would contain all Folders of C:\data but the only files in them would be X days old..

This is what i was using to copy and archive the folders/files BUT it does not take into consideration the age.. IF it did,i would have it delete the files it moves from C:data as they are now backedup in C:\dataBackup

```
$sourcePath = "C:\Data"   
$path = "C:\DataBackup"

$source = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Directory

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

Foreach ($s in $source)

 {

  $destination = Join-path -path $path -ChildPath "$($s.name).zip"


  If(Test-path $destination) {Remove-item $destination}


  [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($s.fullname, $destination)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your script like this:

```
$sourcePath = "C:\Users\kim_p\Downloads"   
$path = "C:\DataBackup"
$tempPath = "C:\DataTemp"

# Any file younger than $limit will be excluded from the zip archive
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)

$source = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Directory

# Make sure the temporary folder doesn't exist
If(Test-path $tempPath) {Remove-item $tempPath -Recurse}

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

Foreach ($s in $source)
{
    $destination = Join-path -path $path -ChildPath "$($s.name).zip"

    If(Test-path $destination) {Remove-item $destination}

    # Create the temporary directory 
    New-Item $tempPath -Type Directory

    # Copy files older than the date set in $limit to the temporary folder $tempPath
    Get-ChildItem -Path $s.fullname -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Copy-Item -Destination $tempPath

    # Create the zip archive using the files copied to $tempPath
    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($tempPath, $destination)

    # Remove the temporary folder and all the files inside of it
    Remove-item $tempPath -Recurse

    # Remove the source files added to the archive
    Get-ChildItem -Path $s.fullname -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
}
```

I added a folder named `$tempPath` that holds the files that will be added to the archive by `CreateFromDirectory`. Files older than some defined limit, `$limit`, is first copied to the temporary folder `$tempPath`, then `CreateFromDirectory`is executed with `$tempPath` as its argument.

Finally `$tempPath` is removed since it's no longer needed.

Please note, before you run this on any files of any importance, do some simple tests. In the end of the script it will remove the files it archived earlier.

In my own tests it appeared to be working but I recommend you verify this as well.

Comment: My God that is amazing. Thank you so much for this. I had another script with a temp directory but couldn't figure out how to remove the source file and keep the folder and don't think I ever would have ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PowerShell v5.0 or superior, try this:

```
  $sourcePath = "C:\Users\kim_p\Downloads" 
  $tempPath = "C:\DataBackup"
  $limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)

  remove-item -Path $tempPath -Force -ErrorAction Ignore -Recurse

  Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse | Where {$_.PSISContainer -eq $true -or ($_.PSISContainer -eq $false -and  $_.CreationTime -lt $limit) } | %{ Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $_.FullName.Replace($sourcePath, $tempPath) -Recurse -Force}
  Get-ChildItem -Path $tempPath -Directory | %{Compress-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath ($_.FullName + ".zip"); remove-item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force    }
```